# Comment traduit-on « packing », comme pour un déménagement ?

Tags: anglais, demande-de-mot

Est-ce qu’il y a un verbe pour décrire ce qu’on fait quand on va déménager et on met ses affaires dans des boîtes en carton ? En anglais je dirais « I’m packing ». Si je cherche cela à wordreference.com il me propose « faire ses valises », mais j’imagine que c’est plutôt quand on part en vacances. Je ne mets pas mes affaires en valises mais en boîtes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En France, quand on déménage, on dira plutôt:

> Je fais mes cartons
>   Je suis en train de faire mes cartons
>   Je suis en plein dans les cartons

L'utilisation de "mes" ou "les" est arbitraire je dirais...